# Problems using Jabber in Emacs on windows

Tags: windows, emacs, client, xmpp

While I realize that the combination of Emacs on Windows as a Jabber client might be the definition of "impasse", I feel like there might be some one else with the gumption and fortitude to get this working (without cygwin, etc).

I'm using GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2010-05-08.

Right now I get a

*connection lost: 'Stream error: Policy violation'*, and a message like so:

*You are using an invalid client, and
therefore will be disconnected. Please ask your system administrator
for client choices.*

The invalid client generates the Policy Violation from what I've gleaned from the XMPP RFC definition.

Any ideas on how to remedy this?  I'm hoping that some where in the jabber.el code I could just have it send a valid client name.

Thanks.

Comment: Which Jabber server is this?  It seems like some Pidgin users get the same error message, which makes me think there's nothing wrong per se with Windows+Emacs+Jabber: http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/7553

Comment: This bug report identifies the server as an Openfire server using the Client Control plugin: http://bugs.bitlbee.org/bitlbee/ticket/631

Answer (score 0):

I have not used jabber (as in jabber.el), so I couldn't speak for it.

I login to jabber/gmail accounts through bitlbee.  It has been working fine for me.  I use it on Linux machines.  Not sure how it works on Windows machines.  Perhaps consider using one of their [public servers](http://bitlbee.org/main.php/servers.html).  I have used their public servers when I use my macbookpro.  They work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In `jabber-version.el`, change the line:

```
(name () "jabber.el")
```

and put something that the server will accept instead of `jabber.el`.  Use <kbd>C-M-x</kbd> after editing to reload the function under point.